# In RabbitMQ save messages to disk, load it after shutdown

Tags: rabbitmq

How can I configure to save all inserted messages to disk that inserted to RabbitMQ
In case RabbitMQ server going down after server up to load the messages from the disk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the queue to durable and the messages to persistent.

```
channel.queueDeclare(<queueName>, true,true,true,null);


channel.basicPublish(<exchangeName>, <routingKey>, MessageProperties.PERSISTENT_BASIC, msg.toBytes());
```